# Azure ACS in a PhoneGap project

Tags: cordova, acs, azure-appfabric, azure-acs

Although this is the first time I'm forwarding a question here, I occasionally find answers to my questions here, so first of all, thanks!

Have someone tried to implant Azure ACS in a PhoneGap project?

I have a working mobile web application (FrontEnd based on MVC + JQM) that i want to convert into a PhoneGap project in order to have a "native client" application.

The application users management based on ACS and forms authentication membership.

I wonder how can I work with the STS token? my first thought is writing a WCF service which will be approached by the client (the mobile device) on success (by realm parameter). the service will authenticate the token and will redirect the application to the authorized zone.

Am I missing something? is there a better faster way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with PhoneGap, but it shouldn't be any different from a regular web site. You will open the app, you will be redirected to the STS (ACS), then you will be redirected to the Identity provider, get a token and finally it will be posted to the app (website)

Since PhoneGap is hosting a web browser, all token negotiation, etc. is automatically handled by it.

Comment: Christian gave me an answer in [Windows Azure forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuredata/thread/c19efccc-4fa5-4eaf-9c87-fa4747d5151c), apparently he just made a prototype and will blog it this weekend.
I'll post the answer when I'll have it working.